# List all elements of quotient group $ G / H $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

List all elements of quotient group $ G / H $ and explain operation.
I solved $ 7 $ examples and it's nice, but I don't know how I must solve these two examples.
$$ i) \ G = (\mathbb{R}^2, +), H = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x + 3y = 0\} $$
$$ ii) \ G = (\mathbb{R}^3, +), H = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x + y + z = 0 \} $$
Could you show me, how I must consider them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think graphically. In $(i)$ the subgroup $H$ is a line through the origin; if you take a point in the plane and add it to everything on that line, you just translate the line parallel to itself, so a coset is just a line parallel to $H$. The other problem is the same sort of thing in three dimensions.

Comment: So it's $ \{ ..., \frac{1}{3}x - 1, \frac{1}{3}x, \frac{1}{3}x + 1, ... \} $ ?

Comment: We just only move the vector?

Comment: @Mat: It’s a whole set of ordered pairs of real numbers. $H$ is the set of all ordered pairs of the form $\left\langle x,\frac13x\right\rangle$. If you add an ordered pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ to each element of $H$, you get $$\left\{\left\langle x+a,\frac13x+b\right\rangle:x\in\Bbb R\right\}\;,$$ which is the set of points on a the line through $\langle a,b\rangle$ and parallel to $H$.

Comment: Yes my fault, I totally forgot about $ (x, y) $. Can I please you about help with $ ii) $ ? Because I've never considered before three dimensions.

Comment: @Mat: $x+y+z=0$ is the equation of a plane through the origin in $\Bbb R^3$. Suppose that $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ is any element of $\Bbb R^3$. Then $$\langle a,b,c\rangle+H=\left\{\left\langle x+a,y+b,z+c\right\rangle\in\Bbb R^3:x+y+z=0\right\}\;;$$ this is the equation of a plane through $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ parallel to $H$.

Comment: Funny, these two examples was the more easier than previous $ 7 $ . Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mat: You’re very welcome.